# writing a file from Set(Crawler,Jsoup,Java)

Tags: java

I recently wrote a small crawler that searches for links on any page, and writes to a file. I added code in the collection (HashSet) to avoid the same links ...

but the code does not work for some reason and the file I see a lot of duplicates.

Could you help fix bugs in it?

here is the code of the crawler:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Crawler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> setUrlBase = new HashSet<String>();
        Document doc;
        String BaseUrlTxtT = "C://Search/urlw.txt";
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/").get();

            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                String UrlLinkHref = link.attr("href");
                if (UrlLinkHref.indexOf("http://") == 0) {
                    setUrlBase.add(UrlLinkHref);
                    for (String strUrlHash : setUrlBase) {
                        writeToBase(BaseUrlTxtT, strUrlHash + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void writeToBase(String fileName, String text) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);

            try {
                wr.write(text + "\n");
            } finally {
                wr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in code

```
String UrlLinkHref = link.attr("href");
if (UrlLinkHref.indexOf("http://") == 0) {
    setUrlBase.add(UrlLinkHref);
    for (String strUrlHash : setUrlBase) {
        writeToBase(BaseUrlTxtT, strUrlHash + "\n");
    }
}
```

you are adding link to set and appending to file entire content of set. I said appending instead of rewriting because you are using

```
FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

where `true` means "don't erase my file, but add new content after existing one" so your file probably looks like

```
link1 //part written when added first link
link1 //part written when added second link
link2
link1 //part written when added third link
likn2
link3
```

(actually since HashSet is unordered elements in each parts could be written as `link2, link3, link1` instead of `link1, link2, link3` but you should get the idea)

To avoid it just use code like

```
String UrlLinkHref = link.attr("href");
if (UrlLinkHref.indexOf("http://") == 0) {
    if (setUrlBase.add(UrlLinkHref)){//will return true if link wasn't in set yet
        writeToBase(BaseUrlTxtT, UrlLinkHref + "\n");// so we also want to write 
                                                     // it to file
    }
}
```

which can be shorten even more using short-circuit-and (`&&`)

```
String UrlLinkHref = link.attr("href");
if (UrlLinkHref.startsWith("http://") && setUrlBase.add(UrlLinkHref)){
    writeToBase(BaseUrlTxtT, UrlLinkHref + "\n");// so we also want to write 
}
```

---

Few more improvements

- To check if string starts with `"http://"` don't use "cryptic" code like `UrlLinkHref.indexOf("http://") == 0` but simply `UrlLinkHref.startsWith("http://")`
- Don't hardcode line separator line `\n` because different Operation Systems can use different sets of line separators (Windows for instance uses `\r\n`). Instead get it from `System.lineSeparator()`. Or even better, wrap your writers in `PrintWriter` which has `println` method (just like `System.out.println()`) which will add line separator based on OS for you.

Comment: Thank you! Could you help in another problem, I thought that the file each reference is a new line, but it turned out that a few links on the same line, and I would like to see a link to one line ..

Comment: @user3384347 Check my last edit, especially point about line separators.

Comment: will try replace the FileWriter to PrintWriter

Comment: @user3384347 I hope you mean "wrap" when you said "replace" :) Wrapping looks like `new PrintWriter(yourFileWriter)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted to do)